# Play framework-2.3.10 application startup issue

Tags: playframework-2.0

I just moved to play-2.3.10 from play 1.

I created my application like this.

```
download activator. 

cd activator-dir
./activator new myapp ply-java

cd myapp
activator
```

ERROR:

```
Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1: configuration not found in commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1 compile
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;2.4: configuration not found in commons-io#commons-io;2.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 compile
[warn]  :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7: configuration not found in org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.webjars#webjars-locator;0.21 compile
[warn]  :: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1: configuration not found in commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 compile
[warn]  :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1: configuration not found in commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-io#commons-io;2.4: configuration not found in commons-io#commons-io;2.4: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7: configuration not found in org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from org.webjars#webjars-locator;0.21 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1: configuration not found in commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 compile
[error] unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3: 'master(compile)'. Missing configuration: 'compile'. It was required from net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.14 compile
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

I don't exactly know what causing the issue. i tried to add those dependencies in build.sbt but still i got this error.

**Edited**

activator version: sbt launcher version 0.13.5

**SBT-FILE:**

```
    name := """MyApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      cache,
      javaWs,
      "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
      "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.7"


    ) 

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
//routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Comment: hello, can you post the result of `activator --version` , the contents of any ".sbt" file in the directory and the content of `project/build.properties` please ?

Answer (score 1):

Using typesafe-activator 1.3.5 on mac OSX and the provided elements, I can not reproduce the issue. 
However, I am pretty sure you only provided extracts of the build definition (`build.sbt`) which should contain a name, a version, possibly an organisation. Unless you provide the full file, it will be hard to tell what is wrong.

In any case the issue is that for some reason you build cannot resolve some of the transitive dependencies for the project. Adding these dependencies as explicit dependencies as you did, will not help.

I also suggest removing the sbt-idea plugin from your build (usually plugins are defined in `project/plugins.sbt`) which should remove at least one of the errors. Current intellij versions are able to import (and refresh) sbt builds making the sbt plugin much less interesting.

You could also look for a key mentioning "resolvers" in the build files ( any .sbt file in the root directory, any .sbt file in the `project` directory, any .scala class in the `project` directory)

If the build definition is ultra top secret, you can reproduce the issue in a sanitized/anonymized project and post that instead.

Comment: I have posted my build. that build was generated by activator when i created my app. 
when i got issue i tried by adding dependencies but still error

Comment: I also tried by removing all extra plugin except play-plugin from plugins.sbt file. but error do not go away

Comment: I got a solution. .invy.cache was corrupted. I deleted .invy directory and run activator command. that error gone away. :)

Comment: glad you found the issue :) happy playing !